# Golang code to upload a file into personal box account

Tags: go

When I give this snippet of code in a golang program after recieving the access token:

```
f, err := ioutil.ReadFile("C:\\Users\\vembu\\Desktop\\hi.txt")
ioutil.WriteFile("hi.txt", f, 0x777)
r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", urlStr, bytes.NewBuffer(f)) 
r.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessobj.Access_token)
r.Header.Add("attributes", "{\"name\":\"hi.txt\",\"parent\":{\"id\":\"3098791209\"}}")r.Header.Add("file", "hi.txt")
```

I get this error:

```
I face &{405 Method Not Allowed 405 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Allow:[GET, OPTIONS, HEAD] Content-Type:[text/html;charset=UTF-8] Content-Length:[0] Date:[Thu, 12 Mar 2015 13:07:32 GMT] Age:[0] Connection:[keep-alive] Server:[ATS]] 0xc08200b8c0 0 [] false map[] 0xc08201f2b0 0xc082060980}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the method to add the attributes and the file name to upload into the box account?

Comment: Not enough information, there's a bunch of variables you haven't included.  Sounds like your url is wrong, or your method is wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

`urlStr` should be `https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content`

https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file

As they show in the docs, you may want to try out your queries using `curl` first:

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST \
  -F attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}' \
  -F file=@myfile.jpg
```

Comment: apiUrl := "https://upload.box.com/"
 resource := "api/2.0/files/content"
 
 data := url.Values{}
 data.Add("access_token", accessobj.Access_token)
 authbear := "Bearer "
 authbear += accessobj.Access_token